# Phonegap/Cordova video record returning 3gp

Tags: android, video, cordova

When I start recording video from my phonegap/cordova app, it's returning a 3gp on a Nexus 7 and Sony Xperia, but an mp4 on most other phones.

It can't be an issue with the camera itself because if I record straight from the camera app, they both return mp4s.

Is there a way to force it to always return mp4 within my app?

Answer (score 0):

When you start capture, you have three arguments :

```
captureVideo(captureSuccess, captureError, options);
```

In options, you may want to set options as described in documentation : http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/cordova_media_capture_capture.md.html#CaptureVideoOptions

Comment: Great in theory, however in practice the documentation states:

"Not supported by any platform. All configuration data arrays are empty."

Under ConfigurationData here: 
http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/cordova_media_capture_capture.md.html#CaptureVideoOptions

So I'm still clueless. :(

Answer (score 0):

in the Capture.java it will call the system method to capture a video,and it will differs when different device

```
private void captureVideo(int duration) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 7){
        intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.durationLimit", duration);
    }
    this.cordova.startActivityForResult((CordovaPlugin) this, intent, CAPTURE_VIDEO);
}
```

if necessary you can change the sourcecode of the cordova ,and use custom video capture